# Apache Spark: issue with map

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

writing a simple join operation on spark and trying to retrieve the values of the map. why i'm getting a syntax issue? what is the correct syntax ?

Spark 2.x

```
joinrdd = webrdd.join(titlerdd)  \
.map(lambda  (k, (v1, v2)): (v1,v2)).groupByKey()


 .map(lambda  (k, (v1, v2)): (v1,v2)).groupByKey()
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right post.

Comment: joinrdd = webrdd.join(titlerdd).map(lambda item : ( item[1][0] , item[1][1] )).groupByKey()   - worked